# Want to fetch url specific value using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have url like this for all product inside a tag "https://www.test.com/brand/product_name" . I want to get product_name click of a tag.

I am not getting how to do this.  If anyone have idea then let me know please.

My code html as follows:

```
<div class="card_caption"> 
<a href="https://www.test.com/brand/product_name" class="more-btn" target="_blank" style="background:#; color:#">know more</a>
</div>
```

Js code as follows:

```
jQuery('.card_caption a').click(function(){
     console.log("working_fine");
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

https://www.test.com/brand/product_name

Onclick of the  tag, I want to get only product_name inside variable. Anyone have idea then let me know.

Comment: Research how to modify a string, or how to parse an url -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

If you `split` the path into an array using the `forward-slash` as the delimiter you simply take the last element in the array using `pop()` method.

```js
jQuery('.card_caption a').click(function(){
     console.log( $(this).attr('href').split('/').pop() )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card_caption"> 
  <a href="https://www.test.com/brand/product_name" class="more-btn" target="_blank" style="background:#; color:#">know more</a>
</div>
Js code as follows:
```